# How to run a bash on a server in background?

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to run a bash script on a server in background?

I know I can use ssh to run a script, but the script may last for a long time, so can I run it  in background? If so, how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

To run a command in the background in bash, you use `&` at the end.

```
./myscript.sh -opt1 > /tmp/myscript.out &
```

Answer (score 2):

[`nohup`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) is your friend, but according to that Wikipedia entry, you can also use `screen`.

1. Login with ssh
2. Run your script in background with nohup as: `nohup script &`
3. Log out: `exit`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a screen manager like [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). You start this (by running `screen`, and then run your process inside it. You can then feel free to simply disconnect your SSH session - the process will continue to run.

Later on, you can reconnect, and run `screen -r` to resume. It will redraw everything like you never even disconnected - allowing you to see the output of your process.